# Custom PageLayoutComponent

Tags: spartacus-storefront

To have specific layout for some pages at our project we create few custom PageLayoutComponent's. Some contfiguration example:

```
{
  // @ts-ignore
  path: null,
  canActivate: [CmsPageGuard],
  component: CartPageLayoutComponent,
  data: {
    cxRoute: 'cart',
    cxContext: {
      [ORDER_ENTRIES_CONTEXT]: ActiveCartOrderEntriesContextToken,
    },
  },
},
```

All work fine with storefront until you will not try to select specific page at smartedit. As result it not use our custom CartPageLayoutComponent, but will use PageLayoutComponent for rendering.

[image]

Probably this is because it's not a normal route navigation. Can somebody from spartacus team suggest how this bug can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

> Probably this is because it's not a normal route navigation

I believe your Route should be recognized normally, there is nothing special in adding a custom Angular Route.

So I guess there is something special about the page or URL of Spartacus Storefront that runs in your SmartEdit.

It's hard to tell the reason of your problem without more debugging.
You said your app works as expected when run differently (locally?), but when used in SmartEdit, then there is a problem. Please identify factors that makes the run SmartEdit different from your (local?) run. And try to isolate them. Guesses from top of my head:

- production vs dev mode of the build?
- exact URL of the cart page?
- any difference in configuration between a local version and deployed one to be used in SmartEdit?

I would also add some debugging code to better know which routes configs are available and which one is used for the current route. For debugging purposes please add the following constructor logic in your AppModule:

```js
export class AppModule {
  // on every page change, log:
  // - active url
  // - the Route object that was matched with the active URL
  // - all the Route objects provided to Angular Router
  constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log({
          activeUrl: router.url,
          activeRouteConfig:
            router.routerState.snapshot.root.firstChild.routeConfig,
          allRoutesConfigs: router.config,
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the issue is how Spartacus handle page preview, you can just try any custom layout and you will be able to reproduce it. For somebody who would like to fix it I can juggest to look into SmartEditService.goToPreviewPage(). So I believe the logic should be, if you preview content page with label '/faq', smartedit service should navigate to route which match with '/faq' URL. See how navigation done in this service to 'product' and 'category' route.

Answer (score 0):

The pages opened in SmartEdit have the same route of `cx-preview` (e.g. to open faq page in smartedit, request is https://localhost:4200/electronics-spa/en/USD/cx-preview?cmsTicketId=xxxxx. backend can get page id from cmsTicketId). If you want to change the page layout, you can consider use PageLayoutHandler. Spartacus has some PageLayoutHandlers, e.g.

```
   {
      provide: PAGE_LAYOUT_HANDLER,
      useExisting: CartPageLayoutHandler,
      multi: true,
    },
```